# ScrollPanel scrollToBottom() not working

Tags: gwt

I'm having trouble getting `ScrollPanel.scrollToBottom` to work. It's not scrolling to the bottom of the panel. Here's an example snippet:

```
FlexTable flexTable = new FlexTable();
// Add loads of rows to the flex table here..
ScrollPanel scrollPanel = new ScrollPanel(flexTable);
scrollPanel.scrollToBottom();
// Add the scrollPanel to the view here..
```

I have also tried using `scrollToBottom()` method in the `onLoad()` overriden method, but it doesn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried scrollToBottom after adding the scrollPanel to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delay the `scrollToBottom()` command, so that the ScrollPanel is ready to take input.

```
Scheduler.get().scheduleDeferred(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
        @Override
        public void execute() {
            // your commands here
            scrollPanel.scrollToBottom();
        }
});
```